# Comma is not working with Bootstrap TagsInput and Bootstrap Typeahead

Tags: tags, bootstrap-typeahead, bootstrap-tags-input

I am going to use Bootstrap TagsInput and Bootstrap Typeahead in one of my project.

When I start typing, Typeahead will show the suggestions. If I press [ENTER], It will add correctly. but there is a problem that when i type somthing and press [Comma button , ]  it do nothing.

Here is my Input:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="false" id="tags" name="tags">
```

JS Codes:

```
$('#tags').tagsinput({
            confirmKeys: [13, 188],
            typeahead : {
                afterSelect: function(val) { this.$element.val(""); },
                displayKey: 'text',
                valueKey: 'value',
                source: [
                    { "value":"test1", "text":"test1" },
                    { "value":"test2", "text":"test2" }
                ]
            },
            freeInput: true,
            itemValue: 'value',
            itemText: 'text',

        });
```

Answer (score 3):

change:
    confirmKeys: [13, 188],

to:
    confirmKeys: [13, 44],

Comment: For anyone wondering, 13 is enter & 188 is comma. I believe 44 is print screen but not sure.